# How to properly send JSON data using SuperAgent on React

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, superagent

I am sending the state of my react app to a server (not located on same as the frontend server).

```
        request.post('http://localhost:8000/guide')
        .send(JSON.stringify(this.state))
        .end((err, resp) => {
            if (err) console.log('Error: ' + err);
            else {
                console.log(resp.text);
            }
        });
```

The problem is at the receiving end (the backend server), I am getting the following on req.body:

```
{ '{"mainColor":"#F44336","accentColor":"#FFC107","appName":"sasa"}': '' }
```

I could work around the problem, but I'd love to figure out the right way to do this, I've tried to send my state without JSON.stringify but I can't nothing on the body of req at my backend. I also tried few other things but couldn't get it to work the right way. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion,

```
    // http request code... use XMLHttpRequest instead of SuperAgent

    let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('POST','http://localhost:8080/guide');
    http.onload = ()=>{
        if (http.status >=200 && http.status <300){
            console.log(http.responseText);
        }
    };
    let state = this.state;
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    http.send(JSON.stringify(state)); // send state as payload

    // server.js in nodejs
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));

    app.use('/guide', function(req, res){
        var payload = req.body; // payload varibale has your state object
    })
```

In this server.js contain body parser, that takes responsibility of your request body and parse your payload object.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was with body parser, I was not using it the right way. much appreciated!